# SSIS ForEach Loop Not Updating Connection WIth Each Iteration of the Loop

Tags: ssis

I have a basic question which I can't address on my own. The basic task is to loop through Excel workbooks and dump the results into a table in a database.

I am using SSIS and am basically following the guide located here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803195/Foreach-File-Enumerator-in-SSIS?msg=5361786#xx5361786xx

The problem I'm encountering is that in the last step when I have to input a variable in the expression of the data connection, it breaks? I've tried setting the expression as both a connection & an Excel file path.

For reference, the relevant parts of the error message are:

> *Error: 0xC0024108 at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 1": The connection string format is not valid. It must consist
>   of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons.
>   This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set
>   on database connection manager. 
>   Error: 0xC0017004 at Package: The
>   result of the expression "@[User::FilePath]" on property
>   "\Package.Connections[Excel Connection Manager
>   1].Properties[ConnectionString]" cannot be written to the property.
>   The expression was evaluated, but cannot be set on the property.
>   Error: 0xC0202009 at Package, Connection manager "Excel Connection
>   Manager 1": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task,
>   Excel Source [2]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager 1" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.*

Comment: What is the value of `@FilePath` when you get the error?

Comment: I thought the value was derived in the loop (as the Variable Mappings section of the ForEach Loop is where I created the variable); but I'm not sure what the actual value is when the connection fails; can you suggest a way to find out?

Comment: Yes, when you run the package in Visual Studio, put a break point on the first component in the loop, and use a Watch to look at the value of the variable.